# Simple way of determining whether a node contains a p tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determing whether a div contains a specific node (in this case, p node). I don't know why but my simple JS isn't working.

Could someone explain why this isn't working?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/OJJxZRb

```js
let test = document.querySelector('div');

if (test.contains('P')) {
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not do `div.querySelector('p')`?

Comment: why not use `querySelector` again - `let test2 = test.querySelector('p');
console.log("-- ", !!test2);`

Comment: See console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented use

```
test.querySelector('p')
```

`test.contains('P')` is

```js
let test = document.querySelector('div');
const pTag = test.querySelector('p');

if (pTag !== null) {
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```

If you wish to use [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), please refer docs. It expects argument as Node and not string

```js
let test = document.querySelector('div');
const p = document.querySelector('.pTag')

if (test.contains( p )) {
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p class='pTag'>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because variable `test` is not a plain text, so `contains` does not work in your code

```js
let test = document.querySelector('div').querySelector('p');

if (test) {
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `contains` you need to pass through a node, however, you're passing through a string and so you're getting an error. The node you pass through must be a reference to a node in the node's childNodes. So, something like this will also fail:

```js
const test = document.querySelector('div');
const p = document.createElement('p'); // create a p node
// check if testt has a child-node which references the same node we created above, this isn't the case, so it will fail
if (test.contains(p)) { 
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```

Instead, you could change your selector to select `p` tags inside `div` tags, and then check whether or not your `querySelector` found a value using your if statement:

```js
const test = document.querySelector('div p');
if (test) {
  console.log('has a p');
} else {
  console.log('has no ps');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>para</p>
  <p>para</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>para</p>
</div>
```